# Using one Array to search a second array for frequency in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an Array-1 say

```
 arr1 =['s','a','sd','few','asdw','a','sdfeg']
```

And a second Array

```
 arr2 = ['s','a','d','f','w']
```

I want to take arr1 and sort the frequency of letters by inputting arr2 with result

```
[s=> 4, a=> 2, d => 3] So on and so forth.
```

As far as I can muddle around.. Nothing below works, Just my thoughts on it?

```
 hashy = Hash.new

 print "give me a sentance "
 sentance = gets.chomp.downcase.delete!(' ') 
 bing = sentance.split(//)
 #how = sentance.gsub!(/[^a-z)]/, "") #Remove nil result
 #chop = how.to_s.split(//).uniq
 #hashy << bing.each{|e|  how[e] }
 #puts how.any? {|e| bing.count(e)}
 #puts how, chop

 bing.each {|v| hashy.store(v, hashy[v]+1 )}
 puts bing
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the frequency of letters by inputting array 2"?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you want to count all letters in the sentence you put in, and not array 1. Assuming that, here's my take on it:

```
hashy = Hash.new()

['s','a','d','f','w'].each {|item| hashy[item.to_sym] = 0}

puts "give me a sentence"

sentence = gets.chomp.downcase.delete!(' ')
sentence_array = []
sentence.each_char do |l|
    sentence_array.push(l)
end

hashy.each do |key, value|
    puts "this is key: #{key} and value #{hashy[key]}"
    sentence_array.each do |letter|
        puts "letter: #{letter}"
        if letter.to_sym == key
            puts "letter #{letter} equals key #{key}"
            value = value + 1
            hashy[key] = value
            puts "value is now #{value}"
        end
    end
end

puts hashy
```